# Checkbox Calculations Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys i have a question about calculating checkboxes and its total in real time so here is my code:

```
function calc() 

{
    theTotal = 0;
    checkForm = document.FormName;
    for (i=0; i <= checkForm.length-1; i++) {
        if (checkForm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (checkForm.elements[i].checked == true) {
                document.getElementById("total").value = theTotal;
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = theTotal;
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<p>Total: $<span id="total">0</span></p>

    <tr>
    <td> <br> <center> <img src="Shirt1.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="shirt1"> <br> <input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" value="19.99"> <label for="rd1">Obey T-Shirt: $19.99</label> </center> </br></td>
    <td> <br> <center> <img src="Shoe1.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="shoe1"> <br> <input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" value="19.99"> <label for="rd1">Shoe - Red Lace: $19.99</label> </center> </br> </td>
    <td> <br> <center> <img src="Snapback1.jpg" width="160" height="150" alt="snap1"> <br> <input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" value="19.99"> <label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $19.99</label> </center> </br> </td>
</tr>
```

When i click on one of the selected checkboxes it won't give me the calculation that i want. Are you able to help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of problems seems in your code. Here I am writing simpler for you.

You don't need to iterate over every form element, even when you are calling it separately  with each checkbox.

You also need to make `theTotal` as global variable for having total of checked items. Right now you are resetting it to 0 on every function call.

You can try this

```
var theTotal = parseFloat(0);

function calc(control) {
    if (control.checked == true) {
        theTotal += parseFloat(control.value);
    } else {
        theTotal -= parseFloat(control.value);
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = theTotal;
}
```

and call it like this

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calc(this)" value="19.99">
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/zaJ7M/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you are not updating the variable total.

You should be reading the .value of the checked inputs